# Operate in data.table column by matching column from second data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to perform a `character` operation (`paste`) in a column from one `data.table` using data from a second `data.table`.

Since I am also performing other unrelated merge operations before and after this particular code, the rows order might change, so I am currently setting the order both **before and after** this manipulation.

```
DT1 <- data.table(ID = c("a", "b", "c"), N = c(4,1,3)) # N used
DT2 <- data.table(ID = c("b","a","c"), N = c(10,10, 15)) # N total

# without merge
DT1 <- DT1[order(ID)]
DT2 <- DT2[order(ID)]
DT1[, N := paste0(N, "/", DT2$N)]
DT1
# ID    N
# 1:  a 4/10
# 2:  b 1/10
# 3:  c 3/15
```

I know a `merge` of the two DTs (by definition) would take care of the matching, but this creates extra columns that I need to remove afterwards.

```
# using merge
DT1 <- merge(DT1, DT2, by = "ID")
DT1[, N := paste0(N.x, "/", N.y)]
DT1[, c("N.x", "N.y") := list(NULL, NULL)]

DT1
# ID    N
# 1:  a 4/10
# 2:  b 1/10
# 3:  c 3/15
```

Is there a more intelligent way of doing this using `data.table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `join` after converting the 'N' column to `character`

```
DT1[DT2, N := paste0(N, "/", i.N), on = .(ID)]
DT1
#  ID    N
#1:  a 4/10
#2:  b 1/10
#3:  c 3/15
```

#### data

```
DT1 <- data.table(ID = c("a", "b", "c"), N = c(4,1,3))
DT2 <- data.table(ID = c("b","a","c"), N = c(10,10, 15)) # N total
DT1[, N:= as.character(N)]
```